# High highs Low lows

Tags: expressions

I don't quite understand this expression:

High highs Low lows

I was looking for a reference and found this: http://www.ulifeline.org/articles/429-the-highs-and-lows-of-bipolar-disorder

Can I interpret that expression as an emotional reaction like "ups and downs"?

Comment: What context did you see this expression in.  Please quote and cite (do both) Ideally, please also link to the source.

Comment: the linked reference doesn't include the phrase "High highs"

Comment: The phrase *high highs and low lows* doesn't sound nearly as natural to me as *the highest of highs and the lowest of lows*, which I think is far more common. For this reason, and as noted in an earlier comment, the article never uses your wording. Probably because it *doesn't* sound quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of to explain is using tides.

You have a High Tide when the sea is up the beach, and a Low Tide when it is far out.

However, for each high or low tide, you get a Spring tide and a Neap tide.

With Spring tides, High tides are very high, and low tides are very low.

Thus, high highs, and low lows.

This is used to relate to the mood/emotion that people with bipolar feel - they're not just feeling slightly low, they are feeling the lowest of lows. They're not just feeling good, they're feeling ecstatic/euphoric. Couple this with the fact they can shift between the high highs and low lows quickly.

So to answer the actual Q in the OP:

It's not just ups and downs as most people would experience, it is really high 'ups' and really low 'downs'